# Do more recent versions of scite crash less often?

Tags: text-editing, scite

Scite is not a bad editor, but the version I have (1.72) crashes on largish ruby files (there's one file that's 65KB it consistently barfs on). Are newer versions any better?

Comment: An editor which chokes on a 65kB file is not a good editor, either. Of course, there may be another explanation. You should consider using a different editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.72 is approaching 3 years old, since then there have been numerous speed and stability updates to SciTE. So yes, new versions are better. Do they crash less often? In general I would say so, but I never really had any great problem with SciTE crashing.

@pavium's suggestion of using a different editor isn't a bad one; if you live in your text editor having something powerful, extensible and readily available is very nice. Both `vim` and `emacs` fit that bill and are a nice way to go for cross-platform, being available on nearly every *nix install. Plus they have huge user bases and you can pick a side and start trolling in the great [holy war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war) that is `emacs` vs `vi`.

If you just want to hack out text and don't care to learn `emacs` or `vim`, there are a bunch of options [Textmate](http://macromates.com) is a joy on the mac, with [E-Text editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) acting similar on Windows. Also for Windows there's [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/), [Notepad 2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) (both being Scintilla based text editors) and [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). Sublime Text is a promising newcomer. There are others (hundreds of others), but those are my picks.

On Windows, between SciTE, Notepad++ and Notepad2 I prefer Notepad++ but Sublime Text is finding its way into my arsenal. I tend to use `vim`/gvim where available on *nix boxes (it just isn't snappy enough on Windows for me).

Comment: I just installed version 2.01 on Windows XP, and it's currently able to handle the file that the old version barfed on. I might look at E-Text editor some day, but they're hoping for you to ... *pay money for it*!1!